# 0 loss Epoch, where is the issue?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
import json
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.utils.data_utils import pad_sequences
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, Attention, Embedding, Dropout, LayerNormalization
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.initializers import GlorotUniform

def create_chatbot_model(vocab_size, max_seq_length):
    input_layer = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,))
    embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 512, embeddings_initializer=GlorotUniform(seed=42))(input_layer)
    lstm_layer = LSTM(1024, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)(embedding_layer)
    attention_layer = Attention(use_scale=True)([lstm_layer, lstm_layer])
    normalized_attention = LayerNormalization()(attention_layer)
    dropout_layer = Dropout(0.2)(normalized_attention)
    output_layer = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(dropout_layer)

    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0005))

    return model



def train_chatbot_model(model, x_train, y_train):
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)
    loss_function = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).batch(128)

    for epoch in range(100):
        epoch_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()

        for x_batch, y_batch in train_dataset:
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                logits = model(x_batch)
                loss_value = loss_function(y_batch, logits)
            
            gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
            
            epoch_loss(loss_value)

        print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}, Loss: {epoch_loss.result()}')



# Load and preprocess the training data
def prepare_training_data():
    with open('training_data.json', 'r') as file:
        training_data = json.load(file)

    user_messages = []
    aim_responses = []
    for dialogues in training_data:
        user_dialogue = []
        aim_dialogue = []
        for turn in dialogues:
            if turn['role'] == 'user':
                user_dialogue.append(turn['content'])
            else:
                aim_dialogue.append(turn['content'])
        user_messages.append(user_dialogue)
        aim_responses.append(aim_dialogue)

    tokenizer = Tokenizer()
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(np.concatenate(user_messages))

    max_seq_length = 30
    x_train = []
    y_train = []
    for user_dialogue, aim_dialogue in zip(user_messages, aim_responses):
        user_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(user_dialogue)
        aim_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(aim_dialogue)
        for i in range(1, len(user_sequences)):
            x_train.append(user_sequences[:i])
            y_train.append(aim_sequences[i])
    x_train = pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=max_seq_length, padding='post')
    y_train = pad_sequences(y_train, maxlen=max_seq_length, padding='post')

    vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

    return x_train, y_train, vocab_size, max_seq_length



# Main code execution
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_train, y_train, vocab_size, max_seq_length = prepare_training_data()

    chatbot_model = create_chatbot_model(vocab_size, max_seq_length)

    train_chatbot_model(chatbot_model, x_train, y_train)

    chatbot_model.save('trained_chatbot_model.h5')
```

I'm having a 0 loss on the 100epoch which means that there is an issue, anyone got an idea? Thanks for your time!

I'm trying to train the neural network, i'm a big noob in that domain but I've high hopes. It looks like the training doesn't work at all

I've made the preprocssing.py code, and the training_data.json also

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site is not a code-writing or tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code. Your question, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Show me a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour], read [what are you asking].

Comment: "having a 0 loss on the 100epoch which means that there is an issue" No, this is completely incorrect.